# How to find player's clothing Roblox Studio

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to create a type of clothing only door in Roblox Studio, like finding their Roblox clothing inventory.  I can't find anything but finding the `player.Backpack`. Can anybody help?

I tried finding the player's inventory by doing
`player:GetInventory()`
but it didn't work.

Comment: Is this a question about all of the clothes that they have bought, or the ones they are currently wearing?

Comment: All the clothes they bought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting to check if they own a specific item, [`MarketplaceService:PlayerOwnsAsset`](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/MarketplaceService#PlayerOwnsAsset) should work. If you are wanting to check if the player is actually wearing a given clothing item, you can either check in the physical character model that exists in the workspace or check a property of their [`HumanoidDescription`](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/HumanoidDescription).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if they own a SPECIFIC item, using [MarketplaceService:PlayerOwnsAsset](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/MarketplaceService#PlayerOwnsAsset) will work.